# Google Maps In Ionic Tab

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, ionic4

I'm trying to get Google Maps working under a vanilla Ionic 4 tab. This is the error I get.

```
Error: Element must be under <body>
at Function.push../node_modules/@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx/index.js.GoogleMaps.create (index.js:208)
at Tab1Page.push../src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts.Tab1Page.initMap (tab1.page.ts:24)
```

Here is the tab HTML.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Find A Store
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map_canvas" style="height:100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the tab typescript.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, LatLng, MarkerOptions, Marker } from "@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('map') element;

  constructor(public googleMaps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform,
    public nav: NavController) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
      await this.platform.ready();
      await this.initMap()
    }

    initMap() {

      let map: GoogleMap = GoogleMaps.create(this.element.nativeElement);

      map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then((data: any) => {
        let coordinates: LatLng = new LatLng(36.06731743465648, -79.79521393775941);
        let position = {
          target: coordinates,
          zoom: 17
        };
        map.animateCamera(position);

        let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
          position: coordinates,
          icon: "../../assets/images/icons8-Marker-64.png",
          title: 'Greensboro, NC'
        };
        const marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
          .then((marker: Marker) => {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
      })
    }
}
```

Since the HTML snippet should already be under the body tag, I'm not sure how this would happen, except maybe that the snippet is rendered before the body is generated. The exception is thrown in the Google maps module in this code snippet in the map create function.

```
if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
    if (!element.offsetParent) {
        throw new Error('Element must be under <body>');
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To Embed native Google Maps views into your app, There are 2 solutions:

**1- Using Element DIV ID:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, LatLng, MarkerOptions, Marker } from "@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public googleMaps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform,
    public nav: NavController) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.initMap();
  }

  initMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create("map_canvas");

    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then((data: any) => {
      let coordinates: LatLng = new LatLng(36.06731743465648, -79.79521393775941);
      let position = {
        target: coordinates,
        zoom: 17
      };
    this.map.animateCamera(position);
      let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        position: coordinates,
        //icon: "../../assets/images/icons8-Marker-64.png",
        title: 'Greensboro, NC'
      };
      const marker = this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
        .then((marker: Marker) => {
          marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
    })
  }
}
```

**2- Using @ViewChild:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, LatLng, MarkerOptions, Marker } from "@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  @ViewChild('map') element: ElementRef;
  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public googleMaps: GoogleMaps, public platform: Platform,
    public nav: NavController) { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log("call ionViewDidLoad");
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.initMap();
    });
  }


  initMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create(this.element.nativeElement);

    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then((data: any) => {
      let coordinates: LatLng = new LatLng(36.06731743465648, -79.79521393775941);
      let position = {
        target: coordinates,
        zoom: 17
      };
    this.map.animateCamera(position);
      let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        position: coordinates,
        //icon: "../../assets/images/icons8-Marker-64.png",
        title: 'Greensboro, NC'
      };
      const marker = this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
        .then((marker: Marker) => {
          marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
    })
  }
}
```

**Note:** You cannot call **this.initMap()** in **ngOnInit()** function, because HTML DOM is not rendered commpletely. So in Ionic 4, you need to call it in **ionViewDidEnter()** instead. For more information, Please read [Ionic 4 and the Lifecycle Hooks in Angular](https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864)

**Screenshot**

[image]

You find my source code here: [ionic4-tabs-map](https://github.com/ManKeomorakort/ionic4-benchmark/tree/master/ionic4-tabs-maps)

Comment: Great explanation, sir!

Comment: It is a great explanation. I'm getting a 404 on something, but that is probably a separate problem (I did take the icon line out). Thank you for your help.

Comment: for icon path, please try to "/assets/images/icons8-Marker-64.png"